# Can a UIView object combine the accessibility properties of its children automatically?

Tags: uikit, voiceover

I have a view hierarchy as follows:

```
UIView
  \-- UIStackView
    +-- UILabel
    \-- UILabel
```

By default, VoiceOver skips over the `UIView` and stops on each of the `UILabel`s separately.

I would like VoiceOver to stop on the `UIView` and combine its contents (i.e. read the accessibility label of each of its accessible children one by one). Does UIKit offer an API to achieve this similar to SwiftUI's [accessibilityElement(children: .combine)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibilityelement(children:)) API?

#### Notes

I know I can set `isAccessibilityElement` to `true` on the `UIView` and then set its `accessibilityLabel` to `"\(label1.text!) \(label2.text!)"`. I'm wondering whether there is an automatic means of achieving this which doesn't require me to define and maintain the `UIView`'s `accessibilityLabel`.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to write some code to reach your goal. 

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping not to hear  Thanks for your input 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIKit does not offer an API like SwiftUI's [accessibilityElement(children: .combine)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibilityelement(children:)) for merging the accessibility labels of all non-hidden children automatically into the parent. I have submitted a suggestion for this in [Feedback Assistant](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) though I am doubtful it will ever see the light of day.

As suggested by an Apple Frameworks Engineer in the Apple Developer Forums [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/723999?answerId=743533022#743533022), a workaround is to define the parent view's accessibility label by means of the stack view that sits between the parent and its children, as follows:

```swift
parentView.accessibilityLabel = stackView.arrangedSubviews
    .map { $0.accessibilityLabel ?? "" }
    .joined(separator: " ")
```